# How to put some text to clipboard using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mozilla

I want to enable user to copy some content to the clipboard. I tried the following.

```
var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
textArea.textContent = response['file_content'];
document.body.appendChild(textArea);

 var selection = document.getSelection();
 var range = document .createRange();
 range.selectNode(textArea)
 selection.removeAllRanges();
 selection.addRange(range);

 if(document.execCommand('copy'))
 {
     console.log('Template copied to clipboard');
 }else {
     console.log('Copying Failed');
 }

 selection.removeAllRanges();
 document.body.removeChild(textArea)
```

But unfortunately

```
document.execCommand('copy')
```

is always returning false in Chrome 68 and Mozilla Firefox 60. It seem to work fine in IE 11. I've already gone through a lot of similar questions on SO, But that all doesn't work for me. I don't want to make use flash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used below code in my project.. Its working for me..

> Element

```
<a rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Copy code" class="copytext-btn copyText" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="code-file-icn"></i></a>
```

> ClickEvent:

```
jQuery(".copyText").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    copyTextToClipboard(jQuery('.GeneratedText').text());
});
```

> Function:

```
function copyTextToClipboard(text) 
{
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    try {
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
        if(successful)
        {
            // SuccessCode

        }
        var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
        console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
    } 
    catch (err) 
    {
        console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
    }
}
```

Comment: document.execCommand('copy') always returning false in my Chrome

Comment: you need to have text selected to return true.